# App freezes after loading Node from Scene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm creating an app with ARKit and it works fine. The only issue I'm having, is that if I want to display a certain Node, the app freezes for about a second. 
I can't come up with a solution for the problem. 
Tried the same code with the same object, just with less texturing and it didn't freeze.

The Scene is 4.2mb but has a lot of texturing. 
Tested on iOS 12.1.0 iPhone Xs Max.

```
   guard let scene = SCNScene(named: "myScene.scn") else { return }

    if let nodeToDisplay = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "nameOfNode", recursively: true) {

            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToDisplay)
    }
```

Comment: have you tried creating the object async? And then adding it to the view?

Comment: I've tried to load the node into a var initially and then adding it to the scene later but, it seems that loading the object isn't the problem. I guess it's the rendering it does in the addChildNode() function

Answer (score 2):

Try using [prepare(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523375-prepare) to add your node.

> By default, SceneKit lazily loads resources onto the GPU for
>   rendering. This approach uses memory and GPU bandwidth efficiently,
>   but can lead to stutters in an otherwise smooth frame rate when you
>   add large amounts of new content to an animated scene. To avoid such
>   issues, use this method to prepare content for drawing before adding
>   it to the scene. SceneKit uses a secondary thread to prepare content
>   asynchronously.

So your code would be something like this:

```
self.sceneView.prepare(nodeToDisplay) { (success) in
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToDisplay)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I just tried it and it improved the process but it still freezes for quiet a time.

Comment: @nico_dkd You're welcome. Your node contains so much details that causes the delay. Is there any extra things you could remove from the node to make it lighter? Another workaround just coming to my mind is to add the node to the scene behind a loading screen or something similar.

Comment: that's what I thought of. If I can't find the perfect solution, I'm probably building a loading screen.

Comment: It improves a bit the process. I add the node from `viewDidApear`and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[GCD](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5370-grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-for-swift-4-part-1-2)** for this,

Just simply use this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToDisplay)
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it didn't change anything

Comment: well usually this is used when you want to update something on the UI , to prevent the application from freezing while its doing async it with the main thread that is mainly holds the UI components, if that did not work, i am probably out of clues